# Вывод списка без квадратных скобок

Tags: python

Рекурсивно перевернуть список. Написать функцию recursive_reverse(some_list).

Код:

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
s_new = []


def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        s_new.append(s[0])
        return 
    s_new.append(s[-1])
    return reverse(s[0:len(s) - 1])


reverse(s)

print(s_new)
```

Ожидаемый результат

> 3 2 1

Вывод

> [3, 2, 1]

> Makefile:5: recipe for target 'run' failed

Comment: Всё правильно выводит https://repl.it/repls/FamousDoubleQuadrilateral

Comment: Тест не проходит. Как убрать [ ]?

Comment: добавил ответ, как убрать

Answer (score 2):

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
s_new = []


def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        s_new.append(s[0])
        return 
    s_new.append(s[-1])
    return reverse(s[0:len(s) - 1])

reverse(s)

print(' '.join(map(str, s_new)))
```

Ещё вариант:

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
s_new = []


def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        s_new.append(s[0])
        return 
    s_new.append(s[-1])
    return reverse(s[0:len(s) - 1])

reverse(s)

print(*s_new)
```

Comment: Все равно выдает ошибку - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from solution import recursive_reverse
ImportError: cannot import name 'recursive_reverse' from 'solution' (/temp/executing/solution.py)
make: *** [run] Error 1

Comment: Ну очевидно, что это проблема в том, как вы запускаете, а не в этом коде

Comment: Предлагаю задать новый вопрос, описав ваше окружение, т.е. файлы и команды, которые вы используете для запуска

Answer (score 2):

Нужно настроть вывод с помощью " "join(s) или print(*s, sep=' ')
Вот код:

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
 
 
def reverse(lst):
    return lst[::-1]
 
print(*reverse(s), sep=' ') #или print(" ".join(reverse(s)))
```

Comment: К сожалению, тест не проходит

Comment: @user394620 возможно дело в типе данних, но я сомневаюсь

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ

```
reverse(s)
for elem in s_new:
    print(elem, end=" ")
```

**Изменено:** по ошибке **ImportError: cannot import name 'recursive_reverse**, предполагаю, что вы где-то неправильно импортировали recursive_reverse (я не знаю, что это)

Answer (score 0):

ребят прост добавьте `*`

```py
x = []
print(*x)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ответ от Васи уже содержит данное решение